# sql join two tables, with non repeating results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables

tbl_a

```
VBID   |   KBID   |   SEQ
 4     |    5     |    1
 4     |    6     |    2
 5     |    6     |    1
 5     |    8     |    2
```

tbl_b

```
VBID   |    more columns to be used
 4     |        bar
 5     |        foo
```

what i got so far is

```
SELECT 
   tbl_b.VBID, 
   tbl_a_a.KBID, 
   tbl_a_b.KBID
FROM (tbl_b 
       INNER JOIN tbl_a AS tbl_a_a ON tbl_b.VBID = tbl_a_a.VBID) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_a AS tbl_a_b ON tbl_b.VBID = tbl_a_b.VBID 
WHERE tbl_a_a.KBID <> tbl_a_b.KBID;
```

the result I'm getting is

```
VBID   |   tbl_a_a.KBID   | tbl_a_b.KBID
 4     |        6         |      5
 4     |        5         |      6                <-- do not need this
```

I don't need that second row (or first) because it represents the same data, what do I have to change in my query to only receive 1 row
the more complicated thing is that I am using ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE tbl_a_a.KBID < tbl_a_b.KBID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter which one you want :

```
SELECT t.VBID,MAX(t.KBID),MAX(t.SEQ)
FROM tbl_a t
JOIN tbl_b s
 ON(t.vbid = s.vbid)
GROUP BY t.vbid
```

Comment: but this doesn't give me the result I am after, i need both kbid wich are represented in tbl_a in two rows as two columns in the query

Answer (score 1):

Add one condition

```
SELECT 
   tbl_b.VBID, 
   tbl_a_a.KBID, 
   tbl_a_b.KBID
FROM (tbl_b 
       INNER JOIN tbl_a AS tbl_a_a ON tbl_b.VBID = tbl_a_a.VBID) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_a AS tbl_a_b ON tbl_b.VBID = tbl_a_b.VBID 
WHERE tbl_a_a.KBID < tbl_a_b.KBID;
```